# Use SSH keys on Dockerfile for Gitlab - Permission denied

Tags: git, docker

Hi !

I'm currently trying to build a docker image, and I need to pull a git project from a remote **GitLab server**. The problem is that the `publickey method` isn't working at all.

The error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

There is the command I launch:

```
docker build . --build-arg priv_key="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" --build-arg pub_key="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)"
```

There is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos/python-35-centos7:latest
USER root
ARG pub_key
ARG priv_key
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh/
RUN chmod 0700 /root/.ssh/
RUN echo ${pub_key} >> /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
RUN echo ${priv_key} >> /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN git config --global user.name "A name"
RUN git config --global user.email "email@address.com"
RUN echo "Host 192.168.1.28\n\tPasswordAuthentication no\n" >> /root/.ssh/config
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/config
RUN ssh-keyscan -t rsa 192.168.1.28 >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh -Tv git@192.168.1.28
```

The problem is, when I check on the output of `ssh -Tv`, it tries to read_passphrase instead of authenticate:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Looks like it wants a passphrase (/dev/tty: No such device or address), but on the host itself, the same command perfectly works:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.28 ([192.168.1.28]:22).
```

Any idea of what's going on ?

**EDIT**:

With the [website](https://vsupalov.com/build-docker-image-clone-private-repo-ssh-key/) @emory provided below, I've tried the code into (and added `chmod` command to avoid a Docker error), set it with the GitLab IP address I have... and it worked !

I've changed the following lines:

```
FROM ubuntu as intermediate > FROM centos:7
apt-get update > yum update
apt-get install -y git > yum install -y git
```

And it worked as well. I've also tried the original one `centos/python-35-centos7:latest`, and it worked. For those who need this, there is the functional code:

```
FROM centos/python-35-centos7:latest
#FROM centos:7
USER root
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y git
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
RUN echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.28 >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh -Tv git@192.168.1.28
```

Comment: I tried building your Dockerfile.  It did not work for me.  I have no idea what you are doing wrong.  However, you should look at https://vsupalov.com/build-docker-image-clone-private-repo-ssh-key/.  (1) They are doing something very similar and it is working for them, so the difference is probably very subtle. (2) Their methodology of using multistage builds to hide build secrets is very clever and you should probably do the same.  (3) There is no reason for you to pass in the public key as a build argument.  We can generate the public key from the private key - `ssh-keygen -f ${priv_key} -y`

Comment: @emory : For the (1) I've added yum update (Did not worked) and changed the image base with centos:7 (I had a different issue, so maybe this is because of the image base I use ?)
(2) --squash does not working if I do not set "experimental features enabled"
(3) Interesting ! I will try to implement it

Comment: Ok so I pushed forward with the example provided on your website, and set it for the GitLab server IP address I have: It worked ! So there is definitely an issue with the OS I've chosen

Comment: @emory Propose your first comment as the answer: The code provided in your link helped me a lot. However, I still do not understand why my original code caused this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the answer is to use a different base image.  `ubuntu` is reported to work.  https://vsupalov.com/build-docker-image-clone-private-repo-ssh-key/ is a good guidance.

Comment: No, My code does not working, the code you provided does :) I've just replaced few things and used the original image `centos/python-35-centos7:latest`, and it  worked :) See the Edit part above for more details :)